# How can i increase load time for bigvideo.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My load times are crazy slow for the small site, what am I doing wrong.
My intentions were to have a image show in place before the video loads  /*
but the image loads at around the same time of the video, even if it takes forever to load.

my html:

```
<div id="bigvid">
  <div class="img">
    <div id="header">
      <div class="inner presentation" style="z-index: 999; height: 100%">
        <header>
          <h1 style="
            font-size: 100px;
            line-height: 65px;
            letter-spacing: 12px;
            font-weight: 900;
            margin: 26px 0;
            color: #f5f4ed;
          ">
            hibidabibi 
          </h1>
          <hr>
          <span class="byline" style="
            font-size: 48px;
            line-height: 65px;
            letter-spacing: 12px;
            font-weight: 900;               
            margin: 26px 0;
            color: #f5f4ed;
          ">
            Coming Soon
          </span> 
        </header>
        <footer> 
          <ul class="icons">
            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-youtube"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-instagram"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
          </ul> 
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my css

```
 #bigvid {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #000;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 100;
   background-image: url('../images/screenshot.jpg');
 }
```

see http://impulse1.github.io/Test/ for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need 100% height on your body. The background image is loading, its just there is no content, until the video loads.  Once the video loads it populates the div and in the split seconds between the div resizing and the video populating you see your background image.

Comment: thanks a lot this fixed it, any tips on how to have the image load and stay in place before the vid loads?

Answer (score 0):

i'd put a much bigger video in there and see if thats true.  Honestly I can see your placeholder image a second or so before video starts.

If you're on chrome.. hit f12 to load dev tools. then switch back to the browser.  Click the refresh button on your site but HOLD down the mouse button, when menu comes up choose the last option - "empty cache and hard reload".

You may just be a victim of caching at this point.

Comment: i think its working fairly well in chrome, the issue is with firefox at this point. The load times are horrendous, but I'll most definitely try